# Display default value in date_popup

Tags: datetime

I can't display the default value of the $date_debut in form. Dpm shows me that the right values are there and I can display $date_debut in #title but not on #default_value.
any idea why ?

```
$timestamp_debut = variable_get('variable_1');
$date_debut = date('d-m-Y',$timestamp_debut);
$form['definition_de_la_période_de_modification']['date_de_debut'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date_popup',
  '#date_format' => 'd-m-Y',
  '#title' => t('Date de début'),
  '#default_value' => $date_debut,
  '#required' => FALSE,
);
```

Comment: Try using `'Y-m-d'` as the date format (and changing `$date_debut` to match)

Comment: it works, thanks. what I wanted is the 'd-m-Y' so I changed code like that :

$date_debut = date('Y-m-d',$timestamp_debut); and format = 
    '#date_format' => 'd-m-Y